# Как выбрать определенную часть из шорткода?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, wordpress

У меня на сайте есть скрипт который из всех картинок в тексте с описаниями (`caption`) по шорткодам выбирает картинки и их описания и складывает в слайдер.
 Все работало на старой версии вордпреса.

Так выглядел шорткод:

```
[caption id="attachment_52788" align="alignnone" width="435" caption="my caption"]<img src="image.jpg" alt="" title="my title" width="435" height="363" class="size-full wp-image-52788" />[/caption]
```

И так код который выбирал картинки и описания

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $output2 = preg_match_all('/caption="(.*?)"/', $post->post_content, $matches2);
    $gallery = $matches[1];
    $captions = $matches2[1];
    $count_of_captions = 0;
    foreach ($captions as $capt) {

        $js .= 'captions[' . $ii . '] = "' . $capt . '";' . "\n";
        $ii++;

        if ($capt != "") {
            $count_of_captions++;
        }
    }
```

Все это работало, но новая версия вордпреса выводит шорткод по другому. Таким образом:

```
[caption id="attachment_52725" align="alignnone" width="440"]<img class="size-full wp-image-52725" src="image.jpg" alt="" height="347" /> my caption[/caption]
```

Как мне заставить скрипт теперь работать? `caption` переместился после тэга картинки.

P.S я попробовал так, но почему то, выбирает только первую букву

```
$output2 = preg_match_all('/\/>(.*?)[\/caption]/s', $post->post_content, $matches2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант решения:

Замените

```
/caption="(.*?)"/
```

На

```
/\/>(.*?)\[\/caption\]/u
```

---

**Обновление**

```
/\/>(.*?)[\/caption]/s
```

Здесь ошибка в том, что не экранированы специальные символы `[` и `]` и вместо окончания `[/caption]` ищется один из символов: `/`, `c`, `a`, `p`, `t`, `i`, `o`, `n`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, подцепляет полностью, но в конце оставляет [/caption]

Comment: да, вы правы, позитивный просмотр вперед добавляет в захватываемую часть свое содержимое. я исправил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь все супер! а вы не могли бы дать ссылку где объяснено было бы принцип этих всех (.*?) ? про preg_match все ясно, но как понять эти маски? столько разных вариантов закарючек видел в примерах, но объяснений не находил. :)

Comment: [`https://habrahabr.ru/post/68345/`](https://habrahabr.ru/post/68345/) и, как ни странно, [`https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения)